Keda can't connect to AWS MQ
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
 name: aws-mq-queue-scaledobject
 namespace: keda
spec:
 scaleTargetRef:
   name: nginx-deployment
 minReplicaCount: 2
 maxReplicaCount: 5
 pollingInterval: 5
 cooldownPeriod:  25
 triggers:
 - type: rabbitmq
   metadata:
     mode: QueueLength # QueueLength or MessageRate
     value: "5" 
     queueName: keda
     protocol: amqp
   authenticationRef:
     name: aws-mq-auth

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: aws-mq-credentials-keda
 namespace: keda
type: Opaque
data:
 username: Yg==
 password: RZg== 
 host: G9zdA==
 tls: ZW5hYmxl


apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
 name: aws-mq-auth
 namespace: keda
spec:
 secretTargetRef:                                                        
 - parameter: username                  
   name: aws-mq-credentials-keda                                                   
   key: username                                                      
 - parameter: password                  
   name: aws-mq-credentials-keda                                                   
   key: password                                                     
 - parameter: host                  
   name: aws-mq-credentials-keda                                                   
   key: host                                                    
 - parameter: tls                  
   name: aws-mq-credentials-keda                                                   
   key: tls


I'm trying to connect KEDA with AWS managed rabbit mq, AWS MQ.
But I can't do it, I followed the steps in the KEDA documentation.
The MQ SG is free on port 5671.
But when performing a description in scaledobject, it reports a problem with the username or password, although they are working.
I use this username and password to log into Rabbit MQ and they work without problems.
kubectl -n keda describe  scaledobject aws-mq-queue-scaledobject
Warning  KEDAScalerFailed         0s (x83 over 18h)  keda-operator  error establishing rabbitmq connection: Exception (403) Reason: "username or password not allowed"


The trigger of RabbitMQ doesn't support parameters a username or password. The username and password should be part of host.

host - Host of RabbitMQ with format ://:/vhost.
If the protocol is HTTP than the host may follow this format
http://://. In example the resolved host
value could be amqp://guest:password@localhost:5672/vhost or
http://guest:password@localhost:15672/path/vhost. If the host doesn’t
contain vhost than the trailing slash is required in this case like
http://guest:password@localhost:5672/. When using a username/password
consider using hostFromEnv or a TriggerAuthentication.

So you need to put your username and password to the host field in your secret.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: aws-mq-credentials-keda
 namespace: keda
type: Opaque
data:
 host: G9zdA==  <----- username and password should be here
 tls: ZW5hYmxl

